# How to dynamically populate values in expression language?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%for(int i = 1; i < pl.getNoOfSegments(); i++){
%>
    <list:column column="segment<c:out value="${i}"/>_value"  titleKey="${pickList.pickListSegment.segment1Label}"  searchType="input" type="nstring"/>
<%
}
%>
```

Here in the above scenario I want to populate the value of the column and `titleKey` but I am unable to use the `${i}` EL and it doesn't giving any terminated error. For `titleKey` the `segment1Label` ie 1 I want to replace with I value but not able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to EL/scriplets as well so this might not be the best way to do it.
What you can do is define a var and increment it manually so it would have the same value as i.

```
<c:set var="count" value="1" scope="page" />  //define your variable here
<%
    for(int i=1;i<pl.getNoOfSegments();i++){
%>                      
       <c:out value="${count} test"/>            // ${count} here has the same value as i

       <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" /> //increment count
<%
    }
%>
```

Alternatively, instead of using Scriptlets, you could look into using JSTL tags such as:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${passedAttr}" varStatus="loop">
```